# How to calculate zoom to preserve map area when changing dimensions?

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the zoom in order to preserve the viewable map area when changing the dimensions (maintaining the same height/width ratio).

So for example I have a map with the dimensions:

1000px x 1200px, zoom: 11.5

Now I want to show that same map but with different dimensions (same ratio):

4000px x 4800px

If I view the map with zoom 11.5 I will get a much bigger area. I want to see the same area, so I need a higher zoom.

I found this formula: [image]

From which I came up with this, which should work according to my very limited maths skills, but it doesn't: [image]

Any hints would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you already take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames?

Answer (score 0):

With dimensions held constant, every successive zoom level halves the distance covered in both height and width. If our dimensions quadruple (4x) on each axis, we need to increase the zoom level such that each axis is a quarter (1/4x) of the distance, to preserve the same area covered.

```
(1/2)^x = 1/4

x = 2

11.5 + 2 = 13.5
```

Comment: thank you, your formula is much easier to understand.